# Getting started with Geb

Tags: groovy, spock, geb

I am new to Geb and Groovy but I have pretty good experience with Selenium 2.0 Automation framework.

Due to some requirement I need to move to Geb. Framework should have
Gradle as build tool, Spock to run tests, Groovy as scripting language and Geb.

I went to [Geb's official website](http://www.gebish.org/) and saw this piece of code

```
import geb.Browser

Browser.drive {
    go "http://myapp.com/login"

    assert $("h1").text() == "Please Login"

    $("form.login").with {
        username = "admin"
        password = "password"
        login().click()
    }

    assert $("h1").text() == "Admin Section"
}
```

but running it doesn't open a browser. Where we are defining browser instantiation like we do in Java: `driver = new FirefoxDriver();`

My questions are:

1. What is the structure of project?
2. How to write `setup()` i.e. browser instantiation and `teardown()` i.e. browser instantiation and quitting methods in Groovy?
3. How to run tests using Spock?

**Edit:**
This is the structure of one example project I downloaded from https://github.com/geb/geb-example-gradle

Where in here we have the `setup()` and `teardown()` method, which initializes the driver and quits the browser? Basically a `BaseClass` that has all initialization and other classes extending it?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

When I was learning Geb, I found this example code very helpful. It's put out by Geb, and integrates with Gradle, and also uses the Chrome and Firefox webdrivers, and PhantomJS for headless operation:

https://github.com/geb/geb-example-gradle

I'm going to answer your questions in slightly different order, which will hopefully help.

Question 1. The project structure is fairly open, as it is built with Gradle, which allows for many options. In the example in the link, there is a `src/test` structure, which is where you can use your normal package structure.

Question 3. You don't have to do anything to run Geb with Spock, but rather, you write your tests using some of the Spock mechanisms, such as `setup:`, `when:`, etc. blocks. You'll actually run the tests with gradle commands, as the example above will show.

Question 2. Because these tests are used with Spock style tests, you can use the typical setup and teardown methods, which are: `setup()` and `cleanup()` which are run once for each test, and `setupSpec()` and `cleanupSpec()` which are run once for each class/spec.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @erdi can you contribute here? I don't understand where is browser instantiation is happening e.g.  we do in JAVA `driver = new firefoxDriver();`? How to have it invoked before every test e.g. we do in TestNG `@BeforeSuite`

Comment: @paul it will be invoked for you automatically before each test. Are you just wondering when it runs, or do you need to have control over the creation of the driver?

Comment: I don't anything to happen automatically. I want to make it happen as per project requirement. I should be controlling it.

Comment: While I would imagine there's a way to control this, I'm afraid that I don't know how - I've just used the built in feature to have it run on its own.